# My PHP function is not returning any values

Tags: php, mysql

```
function GetID($newsTitle){

  mysql_select_db($database_dbConnection, $dbConnection);
  $query_rsGetId = sprintf("SELECT id FROM news WHERE title = %s", GetSQLValueString($newsTitle, "text"));
  $rsGetId = mysql_query($query_rsGetId, $dbConnection) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_rsGetId = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsGetId);
  $totalRows_rsGetId = mysql_num_rows($rsGetId);

  return $row_rsGetId['id'];

}
```

The above code will retrieve the ID when a string variable is passed to it and it will return the ID of that String once it matches in the database, but currently its not returning anything.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the query is correct?

Comment: **0.** Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and removed. **1.** Check `var_dump($query_rsGetId)` to be the right query and put it in phpMyAdmin or something to verify that it's correct. **2.** `database_dbConnection` and `$dbConnection` aren't defined inside the function.

Comment: `$database_dbConnection` and `$dbConnection` don't appear to be in the function scope, the `mysql_*` functions don't exist in PHP7 and using `sprintf` to interpolate the *"title"* is weird (and it'll not have the requisite apostrophes surrounding it) - best to start over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarising everything that I said in comments, which more or less solves the issue. Your code has some vulnerabilities and you need to fix them to make them work:

1. **Please, please, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions.** They are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and are removed in PHP 7. (Latest version of PHP is 7.1).
2. **Global Scope?** The variables `database_dbConnection` and `$dbConnection` aren't defined inside the function. If you are using them from the global scope, please use:

   ```
   global database_dbConnection;
   global $dbConnection;
   ```
3. Use **Error Handling** mechanism to show the errors. One best way to enable the `display_errors`. Set it using the following:

   ```
   // Code
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);
   // php.ini
   display_errors = On
   ```
4. **Correct Query.** Finally, make sure if the query that's gonna be executed is correct. Use `var_dump` or `print_r` to check the output and execute it on the MySQL Server using phpMyAdmin or any other client.

   ```
   var_dump($query_rsGetId);
   ```

Comment: @Hallur Updated. Thanks.